# Getting ActiveRecord association id in callback function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two associated models, employee and doctor:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :doctor, :dependent => :destroy
  ...
end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

When the doctor has already been created and saved.
I want to get access to doctors id in employees after_save callback:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  after_save :save_picture
  ...
  private
  def save_picture
    if doctor
      file_name = 'doctor_' + doctor.id.to_s + '.jpg'
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

I can get access to any doctors method and any of them works fine, but "id" - it returns "nil".
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where my mistake was:

I had a bad accessor in `Employee` class

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def is_doctor= val
    create_doctor if val == '1'
  end
  ...
end
```

It was trying to create a new doctor, but it fault on update action. After that, doctors id attribute in 'self'-object was empty.

The solution was to place association manipulations to another `after_save` callback:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :doctor, :dependent => :destroy
  after_save :save_roles
  after_save :save_picture
  ...
  def is_doctor= val
    @doc = true if val == '1'
  end

  private

  def save_roles
    if doctor
      doctor.destroy unless @doc
    else
      create_doctor if @doc
    end
    @doc = nil
  end

  def save_picture
    if doctor
      file_name = 'doctor_' + doctor.id.to_s + '.jpg'
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your Doctor model have an id accessor?

Try `doctor_id` instead of `doctor.id`, one database query less :)

Comment: I think it have accessor, becouse everything works fine, when I do this:

file_name = 'doctor_' + Doctor.find(:first, :conditions => {:employee_id => id}).id.to_s + '.jpg'

Comment: There is no doctor_id method for employee:  
(undefined local variable or method `doctor_id' for #<Employee:0xa8d8074>)